# Difference between ptr, ptr[0] and &ptr[0] in C strings

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers

I have been studying strings in C, and have been faced with the following problem, in the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
   char *p = "foo";
   printf("%p\t%p\t%p",&p[0],p,p[0]);
   return 0;

}
```

And i have the following output:

```
00403024        00403024        00000066
Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 0.057 s
Press any key to continue.
```

Since p points to the first element of the string, shouldn't p[0] point to the same addres as p (and by consequence, &p[0])?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`p[0]` is not a pointer, it's a `char`.

Since you're asking for `%p` in your format string it gets force-cast to an invalid pointer with the value `0x00000066`, which is just the ASCII value of `f`, the first character in the string.

If you turn on all the warnings your compiler offers you may see one that highlights this conversion and how it's a potential error.

`p` is of type `char*`. `&p[0]` is like `&(*(p + 0))` which is to say you de-reference it to a `char`, then turn it back into a pointer with `&`. The end result is the same as the original.

Comment: Force-casting instead of simply mis-intrpreting seems comparatively … harmless.

Answer (score 2):

You got it almost right. A pointer just stores the address of the pointee that it points to. So outputting `p` outputs the address of the string.

So what does `[x]` do when applied to such an address `p`? It does `*(p+x)`; that is, it evaluates to the value that is stored at this address plus `x`. So in the case of `p[0]`, you get the ASCII value of the char `'f'`, which is 66.

Taking the address of that again by prefixing with `&` gives you the address where it is stored. This is just the address of the original string, of course, because as you observed, the address of the string coincides with the address of its first element.